# Communication issue of Watch app with iPhone app

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I am working on `Watch app` to connect with `iPhone app` and want to handle some functions from `Watch App`. Connected successfully with `WCSession` and sending message successfully when both app are running. 
But my question is how to handle communication between these two apps when `iPhone app` is not running. I want to Watch app to send some message to `iPhone app` and `iPhone app` perform some action s like `API Service Calling`, status changes, status getting etc.

Is it possible to handle like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do [background transfers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession#topics) from watchOS to iOS with `updateApplicationContext([String : Any])`, `transferUserInfo([String : Any]) -> WCSessionUserInfoTransfer`, or `transferFile(URL, metadata: [String : Any]?) -> WCSessionFileTransfer`.

For information on background tasks in iOS, see [Managing Your App's Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle) and [Preparing Your UI to Run in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background).